# Double slash in resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, url-routing

I get a application running over:

Rails 2.3.5, Application is set 2.1.0 at enviroment.rb

Ruby: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.2.0]

The Urls are generated right, but the resources like stylesheets, javascripts are generated with double slashes.

```
<link href="http://127.0.0.1:3000//stylesheets/style.css?1254514155" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This working before I upgrade the mac to snow leopard. I update all following these guides (http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/)

Somebody know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out!

http://loganleger.com/rails-facebooker-double-slashes-resource-routes

Comment: Hi there! seems like the post is no longer available, I have the exact same problem, what was the answer!? Thanks!

Comment: i have this problem too, but this link is dead.

Comment: I have found this page in web.archive.org but I'm not sure that you are using facebooker gem and it will help you also: http://web.archive.org/web/20110525063602/http://loganleger.com/rails-facebooker-double-slashes-resource-routes Good luck!